# How to design the Unity Container?

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, project-structure

I have three projects: *WebAPI*, *Services* and *Repository*.

`WebAPI` has a reference to `Services` and `Services` has reference to `Repository`.

Now I need to add a Unity Container for `Services` and `Repositories` but in `WebAPI` it's doesn't allow to add a reference to `Repository`.

How can I change this in order to obtain the desired design ?

Comment: i dont understand, you say webapi has a reference to repository but it also doesnt allow a reference???

Comment: @Ewan, sorry, my mistake, I mean `"Services has reference to Repository"`

Comment: still shouldnt be a problem unless repository has a reference to webapi